# android: permission denied while opening /dev/video4 (webcam) from JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface, permission-denied, v4l2, v4l

I have configured v4l2 on my android device. I plug the webcam and see that /dev/video4 node is created. But when I try to open it from my JNI layer it says "Permission denied"

I have tried the following

1) Change the permission of /dev/video4 so that it is Read-Write for all (0666)

2) Added the android.permission.camera in the android manifest xml (originally /dev/video4 was created by system and camera group had rw access.)

None of them work. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: try using chmod 777 /dev/video4

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem on Android 4.4.2 *(Sasmung Galaxy S5 SM-G900F)*. I found that changing permissions for `/dev/video4` did not help. But **chown** did the trick:

```
su -c chown 10209:10209 /dev/video4
```

(here, 10209 was the UID alloated by Android to my app).

**PS** this did not resolve my major problem: kernel panic when my app was reading video frames from the particular usb camera.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same issue I had with **SE Linux permissions** on Lollipop. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37646688/641428).

In short, you can:

- disable SE Linux (until reboot) by running (as root) `echo 0 > /sys/fs/selinux/enforce`
- hack your Cyanogenmod build and add `allow untrusted_app video_device:chr_file rw_file_perms;` to `external/sepolicy/untrusted_app.te`.